# Angular 2 observe result of http

Tags: angular

Here I have a Service. Its signIn method will fire a method of another Service which returns an Observable. Every component should be able to subscribe to the result of that Observable. So I created a public response variable as Observable, which can be accessed from every component. I don't think I can directly subscribe to signIn because it requires two parameters which only one Observer would actually know.

The problem is that response is **undefined at the beginning**. So you can't subscribe to it in a constructor of another component.

So how can I subscribe to response when I don't know when the data will arrive? Any ideas?

```
export class AuthService{

    public response:Observable<any[]>;

    constructor(private httpService:HTTPService){
        this.response = new Observable();
    }

    signIn(user:String, password:String){

        this.response = this.httpService.query({user: user, pass: password})
        .map((r: Response) => r.json());

    }
}
```

This is the AuthComponent method where user and password come from

```
onSubmit(f:NgForm){
    this.authService.signIn(f.value.user, f.value.password);
}
```

Comment: "when the data will arrive". What data? Where do `user` and `password` come from?

Comment: @Günter user and password come from a component. Data comes from a http get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you should just return that `Observable`:

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class AuthService {

    public data = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

    constructor(private httpService: HTTPService) { }

    signIn(user:String, password:String): Observable<any[]> {

        return this.httpService.query({user: user, pass: password})
           .map((r: Response) => r.json())
           .map(data => { this.data.next(data); return data; }); // OPTIONAL if you want to store data in you service..

    }
}
```

Other components can now subscribe to that `data` subject.

The calling component will subscribe and its done.

Http-Request-Observables are completed after each request.

Comment: If I subscribe directly to signIn I need to pass user and password. And it will fire http get every time.

Comment: See my updated answer, all other components could now subscribe that `data` subject and will be notified if any other component logs in..